# read a file using the file-system package

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I am trying to read a file using the file-system package.

reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system

The file I am trying to read resides in the same directory as the file executing the read (visual below).

[image]

The code in the reduce2.js file is exactly this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

var output = fs.readFileSync('data.txt')

console.log(output);
```

This is the error I am getting when I run the file from the command line:

```
➜  js-practice node functional-programming-mpj/file-system-and-reduce/reduce2.js 
fs.js:638
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data.txt'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:638:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:540:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jackburum/tutorials/js-practice/functional-programming-mpj/file-system-and-reduce/reduce2.js:3:17)
    at Module._compi
```

which tells me that the file system module can't find the file, but I can't figure out why.

Some other things I have tried:
- I tried using import as well instead of require
- I tried explicitly declaring the current directory, like this

```
fs.readFileSync('./data.txt').
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong or have any thoughts on what I could try to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're executing `node` command from another directory: `js-practice/`.

For `fs.readFileSync('./data.txt');` to work in your case you need to run `node` directly on `file-system-and-reduce` dir

```
file-system-and-reduce $ node reduce2.js
```

Otherwise node tries to search: `js-practice/data.txt` which doesn't exist in your case.

A good solution is to use: [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname), along with `path.join`, in order to get the absolute path to the file, which will allow you to call the script from any location.

```
const fs = require('fs'); // Native fs module
const path = require('path');

const output = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'data.txt'));

console.log(output);
```

Have in mind that the reference you provided, **is not** the native file system module.

- **Native:** https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html (I recommend this)
- **3rd party:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system

Comment: Super helpful answer and got me through the problem. Thanks Marcos.