# Google Drive API : ENOENT - but my file is just in the same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, path, google-drive-api

ENOENT - but my file is just in the same directory ...
Hi all I try to sent a file, birds.mp3, to my Google Drive using API. The file got to be reached by a function to be sent.

Despite that the file I try to send is just in the same folder that the code concerned, my console return me :

> events.js:183
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './birds.mp3'

Here my tree :

```
-- folder
  |-- birds.mp3
  |-- quickstart.js
```

Here my quickstart.js

```
module.exports.insertDrive = function (req) {
  console.log("callback reached.")
var url = req.body.url;
var folderId = 'id';
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': req.body.word,
  parents:  "id"
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'audio/*',
  body: fs.createReadStream("./birds.mp3") // PATH FUNCTION HERE
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  } 
})};
```

I can't figure out why my file can't be reached. I have try several tricks like path.resolve and all, I have try to push my birds.mp3 in several folder if any, but that have failed.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386361/read-a-file-in-node-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read a file using the file-system package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574657/read-a-file-using-the-file-system-package) you're calling `node folder/quickstart.js` instead of `node quickstart.js`, use `path.join` in combination with `__dirname`

Comment: From ``fileMetadata``, I think that you use Drive API v3. If my understanding is correct, after the current error was removed, the file cannot be uploaded to the folder of ``"id"``. So please modify from ``parents: "id"`` to ``parents: ["id"]``. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to load a file from the same directory as the current module and pass that to the Google API, then use `__dirname` instead of `./`.   The `./` uses the current working directory which will depend upon how the overall program was invoked and will not point at your module directory.

So, if the intended file is in the same directory as your module, then change this:

```
fs.createReadStream("./birds.mp3")
```

to this:

```
fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, "birds.mp3"));
```

Comment: it's works, I would a precision if possible, if I seek for a "blob:http/[path]" as I have done today, how reach this path. Because it's caused me an ENOENT also.

Comment: @Spiderman - I don't understand your comment.  If you need help with something else, you can write a new question and describe the new problem in detail in that new question.